# Why is there "undefined" in the console?

Tags: javascript, this

Question about javascript from a rookie.
I need your help, thank you.

[image: code]

Comment: In the future, please post your code and not images of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It says `undefined` because nothing get returned by the function `sayHi` ; and you are displaying the return of the function.

```js
function sayHi() {
  console.log('Hello');
}

console.log(sayHi());

function sayHi2() {
  console.log('Hello');
  
  return 'returned value';
}

console.log(sayHi2());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you `console.log()` your `console.log()`.

You only need to call `instructor.sayHi()` or your sayHi function should return a string that you `console.log()`.

Comment: He's displaying the return of the function `sayHi`, not the `console.log`